# SAPUI5 When clicking on UploadCollectionItem it navigates to Shell-home on mobile devices

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have an app with a UploadCollection. When downloading uploaded files on a mobile device, the file gets downloaded and i'm getting navigated back to Shell-home instead of staying in my current application.

This only happens on mobile devices, on desktop devices, only the file gets downloaded an i stay in the current app.

You can see the url change to xxxx/FioriLaunchpad.html# when clicking on the attachment.

I already tried calling preventDefault() to prevent from navigating, i tried to replace the url with the previous one to stay in my current app with "window.location.replace" and i tried calling windows.history.go(-1).

Is there a way to disable the standard behavior of these links?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.